# Avoid scientific notation when using python csv writerow

Tags: python, csv

I have this excel file:

```
DB      client_id    client_name   Joining Date
13542   0021I156    Loyiso Dwala   2013-04-05
13077   0043E03     Attwell Fayo   2013-04-06
13155   0023G025    David Mbhele   2013-04-07
```

I am using the following python script to convert this into a csv file:

```
import xlrd
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with xlrd.open_workbook('myexcelfile.xlsm') as wb:
    data = wb.sheet_by_index(2)
    column_date = 5 
    with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:
        c = csv.writer(f)
        c.writerow(data.row_values(6))
        for r in range(7,data.nrows):
            year, month, day, hour, minute, sec = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(int(data.row_values(r)[column_date]), wb.datemode) #unpack all values here, not just year, month, day
            py_date = datetime(year, month, day)
            py_date_2 = py_date.date()
            c.writerow(data.row_values(r)[:5]+[py_date_2] + data.row_values(r)[6:])
```

This is the output:

```
DB      client_id    client_name   Joining Date
13542   0021I156    Loyiso Dwala   2013-04-05
13077   4.30E+38    Attwell Fayo   2013-04-06  <--
13155   0023G025    David Mbhele   2013-04-07
```

As you can see, the client_id column has converted `0043E03` to `4.30E+38`.
From researching this I realise I have to do something with the formatting, ie:

```
'%f' % client_id
```

but how do I do this specifically for the client_id column when using csv writer?

Comment: Mostly a wild guess since I have neither your excel file nor Excel itself FWIW so I can't test, but I assume Excel is trying to be smart (and fails...) and seeing something looking more or less like a float in scientific notation happily convert it to a float...  IOW you should test what you get in your excel rows and convert it back to string if necessary, or fix you excel sheet so it does NOT try to be smart. My 2 cents...

Comment: Could you convert it to a string before writing the row?

Comment: how do I convert to a string before writing the row? beginner ... :/

Comment: Are you sure the data is correctly displayed in Excel? Excel will also make that conversion if entering `0043E03` into a column formatted as `General`. I suggest you try and use `Format Cells...` to change the column format for `client_id` to `Text`.